# How do I change android:defaultValue for an argument in the version 2.7.5 androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

In 2.7.3 and 2.7.4 it worked
navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph, bundleOf("sslovo" to SkyConstants.skyStartSlovoSearch))
Now in version 2.7.5 I observe that the command .setGraph stopped cheating android:defaultValue for an argument.
How inversion 2.7.5 to programmatically set a different value for android:defaultValue?

```
        id ("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")  version "2.7.5" apply false
         // Navigation
            implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
            implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")
```

```
        command in Acivity:
         val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment =
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(mainBinding.navHostFragment.id) as NavHostFragment
             navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Then in Acivity the value changes sslovo:

```
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph, bundleOf("sslovo" to SkyConstants.skyStartSlovoSearch))
```

Everything works fine in the version 2.7.3 and 2.7.4.
When connecting the version 2.7.5: command .setGraph does not work and sslovo always matters "main".
What has changed and how in the version 2.7.5 programmatically set a different value for android:defaultValue.

My code:

````
nav_graph.xml:
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/SkySearchFragment">
    <!--app:startDestination="@id/SkySearchFragment"-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SkySearchFragment"
        android:name="com.dinadurykina.skylexicon.ui.search.SkySearchFragment"
        android:label="@string/bar_search_translate"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sky_search">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SkySearchFragment_to_SkyMeaningsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SkyMeaningsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
        <argument
            android:name="sslovo"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="main" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SkySearchFragment_to_DialogImageFragment"
            app:destination="@id/DialogImageFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SkySearchFragment_to_SkySettingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SkySettingsMainFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment```
````

Comment: What you pass to `setGraph` should always take precedence, so this may be a regression. If you can reproduce this in a sample project, it would be helpful if you could [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828&template=1093757) so that this can be fixed on the library side.

Comment: You aren't also using `app:navGraph` in your XML though, are you? If you are using `setGraph` you can't use that.

Comment: Thanks for the rest of the second tip. Removed from the code app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" from XML.
.setGraph began to work correctly. There is no need to fix anything in the library for this occasion. There is no mistake.
Maybe I missed it, and maybe it would be good to clarify in the documentation that app:navGraph=CANNOT be specified in XML when using .set Graph.
Thanks again.